# Bootstrap modal getting pushed to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

Using Bootstrap 3 in rails 4 app, I'm calling a modal with:

```
  <a href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> New Listing</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Hey, wait a second!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            In order to blah blah...!
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, type: "button" , class: "btn btn-primary" , method: :delete %>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Everything is working well, except when I the modal executes, it's pushed off the right of the screen:
[image]

My modal CSS is:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I tried changing position to absolute, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Any recs?

Comment: how is your grid layout structured? can you check is it correct? I think there could be something wrong that messes up your modal box, cause its code seems correct

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand.  One of the places I'm using this modal (and having the problem) is in the navbar.  This shouldn't be impacted from the grid layout, correct?

Comment: well also the navbar is inside the grid layout, try to check if; otherwise you could have been redefining some shared classes. seems strange behaviour

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance- new to developing.  Can you please detail how I go about checking the grid layout.  I assumed this only pertained to areas that leverage bootstrap's grid rendering (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html).  Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a CSS issue.  I'm using a bootstrap theme from Bootswatch.  After overriding Bootswatch's modal CSS elements with the standard bootstrap code, all was fixed.  Thanks.